# Sample code of java lucene indexing and searching for creating one document per line

Tags: lucene

I am very new to lucene.I have a text file containing 100s of records with two columns per line.First column is of userid and second is of url_list(I guess those will be my document fields)

I need to provide a search feature using lucene which will give the document containing entered url or userid. And for that i need to create one lucene document per line of my text file.

**Please suggest me some sample code for this**..

**I m using lucene version 3.6.2**

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short but fantastic tutorial on Lucene for starters.

[Lucene in 5 minutes](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)

---

Steps

1) I assume that you are pre-parsing the text file to get hold of userid, corresponding url list. You've got to do this. Lucene won't help. Lucene does break the text that belongs to a single field, but won't break the text and add userid to userid field and urls to URL field.

2) Read the above tutorial. I highly recommend you to use the [latest version](http://lucene.apache.org/) of Lucene which is 4.1 as of now.

3) Things to remember that are specific to your use-case

- Have two fields for each document: USER_ID, URL (of course you may change those names)
- Do not ANALYZE (break into tokens) the content of USER_ID field.
- I am not sure how you wanna store the URL field. You may not want to ANALYZE it or use the StandardAnalyzer which recognizes a URL without tokenizing.

4) You can find the sample code to index, query, search, retrieve results in the tutorial.

Comment: hi,                                                                  Thanks for help..But i didn't get any source code for creating 1 document per line..What should i use for that? Also i have a text file such as--> useripaddress url...I just need to create and index document for such line.

Comment: you mean parsing the text file you have? That doesn't belong to Lucene.. code can be written only you can provide a sample of text you have in that file and with clear explanation about the way you want it to be indexed.